# Where does Windows 10 (Chrome or Edge) stores the data of an installed PWA?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, operating-systems

I want to be able to transfer an installed PWA to an offline PC.

When "installing" it via the browser an link is created:

EDGE

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge_proxy.exe" --profile-directory=Default --app-id=gkmcnoliljcljlneolhfcbhddfghlipa
```

CHROME

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome_proxy.exe" --profile-directory=Default --app-id=gkmcnoliljcljlneolhfcbhddfghlipa
```

How can I find out where the `app-id` is linking to?

Comment: `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Extensions` || `%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions` _(if that's not the directory you're looking for, it will be within a subdirectory of `User Data`)_

Comment: Thank you very much! On my machine it is found here:

%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Extensions
%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions